# Difference between print() and println()

Tags: arduino-ide

What is the difference between print( ) and println( )?
I see none when I run a code.

Comment: Really? Try a few of each in sequence and see if you see any difference.

Comment: Ya, now I see a difference

Comment: The answer to this question could have easily be found on the Arduino site.

Comment: The `ln` from `println` comes from `line`, meaning it will print a new line character at the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

print() prints whatever you send in.
println() does the same thing, only after using println, anything new that is printed gets printed in next line, I.e. a new line is formed.

Comment: Could you post your code please, as my answer is kind of incomplete now.

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to see the difference is using `Serial.print();`/`Serial.println();`.

```
print();
```

will print out whatever you input wherever the cursor currently is. For example:

```
Serial.print("Test");
Serial.print("Words");
```

This will print:

```
TestWords_
```

The underscore marks where the cursor is (and therefore where the next print command will start). In contrast, the code:

```
Serial.println("Test");
Serial.println("Words");
```

will print the following:

```
Test
Words
_
```

You can also print multiple statements and then follow with `println` like so (note the space at the end/beginning of the strings):

```
Serial.print("These ");
Serial.print("Test");
Serial.println(" Words.");
```

to get the following output:

```
These Test Words.
_
```

You can also use `println();` to add a newline character in general. If you would print a variable that doesn't return a newline character, `println();` can be used for formatting. Example:

```
int x = 50;
Serial.print(x);
Serial.println();
```

This will print:

```
50
_
```

Finally, you can add in special characters like a tab `\t` inside your quotes for formatting. Example:

```
Serial.println("Test\tTest")
```

This will return:

```
Test    Test
_
```

Comment: Your answer tells us that println() function prints what's in the parenthesis then prints a newline character rather that printing a newline character first and then printing what's inside the parenthesis. Your idea of underscore for showing the cursor position is quite very nice. +1 for all that.

Answer (score 1):

The print("aString") method prints just the string "aString", but does not move the cursor to a new line. Hence, subsequent printing instructions will print on the same line.

The println("aString") method prints the string "aString" and moves the cursor to a new line.

The println() method can also be used without parameters, to position the cursor on the next line.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

print() print which you want but in one line.

For example,

```
Serial.print("Hello");
```

Then output in Serial Monitor look like,

```
HelloHelloHelloHelloHello
```

println() print same things but in new line.

For example,

```
Serial.println("Hello");
```

Then output in Serial Monitor look like,

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```